# How do I group objects by similiar items that they contain?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have 10,000 baskets.
In each basket, I have 10 food objects, no repetitions.

I need to group baskets in groups where all baskets in the group have >=6 of the same objects within them, with no repetitions in any group. Basically, if a group has `basket1`, `basket2`, `basket33`, `basket 123`, then no other groups will have them.

When I try to do it with combinations, I end up with many redundant groups.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, List
import random
from uuid import uuid4
import attr

T = TypeVar("T")

food = ['apple', 'banana','grapes','orange','potato','kiwi','pomegranate','blueberry','strawberry','cantalope','honeydew','papaya','mango','raspberry',
        'celery','carrot','potato','raddish','lettuce','tomato','garlic','onion','cabbage','corn','shallot','peas','squash','broccoli','spinach']
        #'pasta','sugar','flour','honey','salt','pepper','corn starch','baking soda','cinnamon','paprika','butter','cream','chocolate']

@attr.dataclass
class Basket(Generic[T]):
    items: List[T]
    volume: int
    id: str = attr.ib(factory=lambda: str(uuid4()))


#Generate baskets
basket_names = [f"basket{i}" for i in range(1, 10001)]
baskets: List[Basket[str]] = [
    Basket(items=random.sample(food, 10), volume=random.randint(0, 1000), id=name)
    for name in basket_names
]
```

Comment: So you have 10000 baskets, and 10 food objects per basket. How many distinct types of food are there?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [scikit-learn: clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: You have two potatoes in your food.

Comment: A (trivial) solution is to put each basket into a group of its own. Of course it is not what you are after. You have to formulate what are you trying to optimize. Is it number of groups perhaps? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using scikit-learn.

- [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer) to transform each basket into a 0-1 vector with one coordinate per food type;
- [`sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) to make clusters, with baskets in the same cluster if they differ by at most 8 food types (8 = 2 * 4 = 2 * (10 - 6), so if two baskets have exactly 6 food types in common, then their vectors will differ by 8 coordinates)
- AgglomerativeClustering().fit_predict() returns a list of numbers: number `x` at index `i` in the list means that the `i`th basket is in the `x`th cluster.
- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can be used to get the clusters as a list of lists of baskets.

```py
import random
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

n_baskets = 10000
n_foodperbasket = 10
n_samefoodpercluster = 6
max_volume = 1000

food = sorted(['apple', 'banana','grapes','orange','potato','kiwi','pomegranate','blueberry',
 'strawberry','cantalope','honeydew','papaya','mango','raspberry', 'celery','carrot',
 'raddish','lettuce','tomato','garlic','onion','cabbage','corn','shallot',
 'peas','squash','broccoli','spinach']) # removed your duplicate 'potato'

baskets = [(random.sample(food, n_foodperbasket), random.randint(0,max_volume), i) for i in range(n_baskets)]

vectorbaskets = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=food).fit_transform([b[0] for b in baskets])

clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, distance_threshold=2*(n_foodperbasket - n_samefoodpercluster))
clusters = clustering.fit_predict(vectorbaskets)

groups = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(zip(clusters, baskets)), key=itemgetter(0))]

print(groups)
```